# Nano: Remember cursor position at start

Tags: vim, nano

Can Nano save the current position of the cursor at exit and, when you reopen the file, restore the old cursor position, like vim does?

Comment: No.  If you want an editor with features, use an editor with features.  nano's purpose is to be a minimalist, simple editor with almost no features.

Comment: don't think so, but you can open file at a certain line `nano +65 /path/to/file`. Not what you are looking for, I see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ubuntu 2018. In `~/.nanorc` put:

```
set positionlog
```

Just as a tip, I also have these:

```
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
set autoindent
set smooth
```

Comment: Thank you. I found very useful also these options: `set atblanks`
`set constantshow`
`set linenumbers`
`set mouse`
`set softwrap`

Comment: I tried also to add `set historylog` and `set backupdir /tmp/nano/`, but it seems they does not work.

Comment: works in centos 9

Answer (score 3):

`nano` has a compile-time option to support this feature, in [`nano.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/nano.c#n2587), added in [February 2011](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/commit/src/nano.c?id=9bfda9196bb0a07f071012d44223000abdb55e5d):

```
#ifndef DISABLE_HISTORIES
        else if (ISSET(POS_HISTORY)) {
            ssize_t savedposline, savedposcol;
            /* If edited before, restore the last cursor position. */
            if (check_poshistory(argv[i], &savedposline, &savedposcol))
            do_gotolinecolumn(savedposline, savedposcol,
                        FALSE, FALSE);
        }
#endif
```

The corresponding changelog entry is

```
2011-02-18 Chris Allegretta <chrisa@asty.org>                                  
        * New saved cursor position history option.  Command line option -P or --poslog, rc file
          entry "poslog".  Search history changes to ~/.nano/search_history, cursor position log
          is ~/.nano/filepos_history.  Added checks to move the legacy .nano_history file to the
          new location.  Several new functions to files.c: load_poshistory(), save_poshistory(),
          check_poshistory(), update_poshistory(), and reworking of histfilename().  New FAQ entry
          4.15 discussing the change and offering an interoperability workaround.
```

It is ifdef'd (may not be available in your packaged version).  But if available, this is configured with `-P` (command-line option) or `positionlog` (or `poslog`, deprecated) in the `nanorc` file.

Comment: The positionlog option is enabled by default in my Debian and CentOS machines, but not on a debian production server I happen to be using today.